# How to open an in-memory web page with WebView2?

Tags: c++, microsoft-edge, webview2

My C++ code has these steps, trying to get JavaScript-generated HTML codes.

1. Call `ICoreWebView2Settings::put_IsScriptEnabled` to turn on JavaScript feature
2. Call `ICoreWebView2::NavigateToString` to set an in-memory webpage.
3. When `NavigationCompleted` happens, we harvest the HTML codes of the entire web page.

Unfortunately, there is apparently a race condition. Sometimes, JavaScript codes in `<body>` are ignored, and only the JavaScript codes in `<head>` have effect. Sometimes, we get `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`.

When using `ICoreWebView2::Navigate` to open a remote web page, I didn't see this problem. It seems a bug in `ICoreWebView2::NavigateToString`. Therefore, replacing `ICoreWebView2::NavigateToString` with `ICoreWebView2::Navigate` seems to be a better choice, but I don't know how to use `ICoreWebView2::Navigate` to open an in-memory HTML document. What scheme shall I use? `file://` or `memory://`, etc.? Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried many ways to have JavaScript-rendered code, the best one I got is:

1. Call `ICoreWebView2::AddWebResourceRequestedFilter` and `ICoreWebView2::add_WebResourceRequested` to enable a pseudo URI, e.g. "file://in-mem/doc".
2. In the callback of event `WebResourceRequested`,

   1. Call `ICoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs::get_ResourceContext` to get the request.
   2. Call `ICoreWebView2Environment::CreateWebResourceResponse` to create the response.
   3. Call `ICoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs::put_Response` on the argument of the callback.
3. In the callback of event `NavigationCompleted`, we harvest the JavaScript-rendered HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#syntax) in `ICoreWebView2::Navigate`. Data URLs start with the `data:` scheme, you can use `data:text/html,` to show the HTML content. You can refer to the sample code below:

```
webviewWindow->Navigate(L"data:text/html,<h1>Hello, World!</h1> <script>alert('hi');</script>");
```

The code above will show a HTML document with "Hello, World!" and executes a JavaScript alert.

[image]

Comment: I just tried this, and noticed that the URI seems to have length limitation. It dose work but only when the document is small. The safer way is to use event `WebResourceRequested`, but according to the official manual the scheme has to be file://, http:// or https://.